# How to execute the .sql file sequencially using WinRM - SQL Server DB Deployment task?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the *WinRM - SQL Server DB Deployment* task for database deployment.

I have set the property of Deploy SQL Using to `*Sql Query File*`

I have a Folders as below in source control -

SchemaModifications
DataInsertion

I have .sql Scripts in SchemaModifications as below

```
`1_City.sql
2_Statesql
|
|
|
100_Country.sql`
```

I have .sql Scripts in DataInsertion as below

```
`1_ABC.sql
2_pqr.sql
|
|
500_XYZ.sql`
```

How can I execute the scripts sequencially from the folder i.e script 1 to n

What path I need to give at *Sql File* to meet above requirement.

Currently I have given below path to execute the Scripts from SchemaModifications folder.

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/SchemaModifications/*.sql
```

But its not working

please let me know what changes I need to do

Comment: Don't just run SQL scripts. Use a SQL change management tool like SQL Server Data Tools. Or write a single "entry point" script that calls your scripts in the correct sequence.

Comment: @DanielMann 

Thanks for the reply. I am already using SSDT for generating and Deploying the database changes.
My Problem statement is in terms of MetaData insertion in the DB.
Security perspective the sql files are not kept in the source control repository. 
As a reason I want to execute the scripts in a sequential manner.